# How to make gitlab-runner read from a specified file instead .gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using `gitlab-runner` locally with `sudo gitlab-runner exec docker [job name]` in the root of a repository which contains the `.gitlab-ci.yml`. Is it possible to read the runner configuration from another file than `.gitlab-ci.yml`?

I'm aware that I can manage different configurations in different jobs in the same `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

I'm aware that `gitlab-runner exec` has been deprecated with a plan to replace it only, but no realization yet (see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2797 for details), so I'm thankful for suggestions regarding the successor as well.

I created https://gitlab.com/krichter/gitlab-runner-local-different-name with a YAML named `a` containing a "Hello world"-`echo` in a job called `main` which I'd like to run as an example without the need to rename `a` to `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

Running it with `sudo gitlab-runner exec docker main --env CI_CONFIG_PATH=a` fails due to

```
WARNING: Since GitLab Runner 10.0 this command is marked as DEPRECATED and will be removed in one of upcoming releases 
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
FATAL: open .gitlab-ci.yml: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really you can't: `.gitlab-ci.yml` is hardcoded into the `gitlab-runner exec` code. I've created [issue about this problem](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/3419).  Please upvote it if it still relevant for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can `gitlab-runner exec docker job --env CI_CONFIG_PATH=[pathtoyml]`

See:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/312

See also:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html

Comment: `gitlab-runner exec shell job --env CI_CONFIG_PATH=[pathtoyml]` fails with a valid GitLab CI Yaml named `a` with `gitlab-runner` 10.5.0.

Comment: Any specific error? `sudo gitlab-runner exec docker [job name] --env CI_CONFIG_PATH=a` fails too? Did you try to set the Variable in your Gitlab Project?

Comment: I added an example project to the question and the output the commands suggested by you. Setting the variable (I'm assuming you're referring to secrect input variables in the CI settings) in the project has no effect.

Comment: How does gitlab runner sees git repo? Do you mount it with volume?

Comment: It doesn't work because path is hardcoded in `gitlab-runner exec` code.